# Javascript list of map's keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, dictionary, foreach

I'm trying to do a `forEach` on a map like this :

```js
//Initialisation de la map couleur
var mapCouleurs = new Map();
mapCouleurs.set("Blanc", "white");
mapCouleurs.set("Rouge", "red");
mapCouleurs.set("Bleu", "blue");
mapCouleurs.set("Vert", "green");
mapCouleurs.set("Orange", "orange");
mapCouleurs.set("Violet", "purple");
mapCouleurs.set("Jaune", "yellow");
mapCouleurs.set("Gris", "grey");
mapCouleurs.set("Noir", "black");

for (var key in mapCouleurs) {
    document.getElementById("color").innerHTML += "<option value='" + mapCouleurs[key] + "'> " + key + "</option>";
}
```

```html
<select id='color'></select>
```

I tried a lot of method, like the `map.forEach()` with the callback (I think I didn't really understood it) or even the jQuery with `$.map` or `$.each` but I have no result! Can you please help me to resolve it.

Comment: `mapCouleurs.forEach(function(value, key){document.getElementById("color").innerHTML += "<option value='" + value + "'> " + key + "</option>";})`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm pretty sure he's using the built-in `Map` object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is `for of` not `for in`

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud yeah, my bad.

Comment: And `Map` has a `forEach` method

Comment: The map object exist in JS, i need to use it for the couple key/value, i can't use a simple array

Comment: And you're sure you're not just looking for an object ?

Comment: @MaximeOzenne he wasn't talking about an array. He was talking about an object. A JavaScript object ... `{ key: value}` ... is nothing more than a dictionary itself. In your case the `Map` and `object` are the same thing.

Comment: Omg my bad, I used Map for something else and i thought i could only use it for my new problem. Object can solve easily my problem... Thanks

Comment: Yes, it does seem like an object would work just fine for this.

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this:

```js
//Initialisation de la map couleur
var mapCouleurs = new Map();
mapCouleurs.set("Blanc", "white");
mapCouleurs.set("Rouge", "red");
mapCouleurs.set("Bleu", "blue");
mapCouleurs.set("Vert", "green");
mapCouleurs.set("Orange", "orange");
mapCouleurs.set("Violet", "purple");
mapCouleurs.set("Jaune", "yellow");
mapCouleurs.set("Gris", "grey");
mapCouleurs.set("Noir", "black");

mapCouleurs.forEach(function(value, key)
{
   document.getElementById("select").innerHTML += "<option value='" + value + "'> " + key + "</option>";
})
```

```html
<select id='select'></select>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var colors = new Map();
var select = "";

colors.set("Blanc", "white");
colors.set("Rouge", "red");
colors.set("Bleu", "blue");
colors.set("Vert", "green");
colors.set("Orange", "orange");
colors.set("Violet", "purple");
colors.set("Jaune", "yellow");
colors.set("Gris", "grey");
colors.set("Noir", "black");

for (key of colors.keys()) {
  select += "<option value='" + colors.get(key) + "'> " + key + "</option>\n";
}
```

console.log(select);

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
//Initialisation de la map couleur
var mapCouleurs = new Map();
mapCouleurs.set("Blanc", "white");
mapCouleurs.set("Rouge", "red");
mapCouleurs.set("Bleu", "blue");
mapCouleurs.set("Vert", "green");
mapCouleurs.set("Orange", "orange");
mapCouleurs.set("Violet", "purple");
mapCouleurs.set("Jaune", "yellow");
mapCouleurs.set("Gris", "grey");
mapCouleurs.set("Noir", "black");

mapCouleurs.forEach(function(value, key)
{
   document.getElementById("color").innerHTML += "<option value='" + value + "'> " + key + "</option>";
})
```

```html
<select id='color'></select>
```

Comment: Thanks this is the best answer for my problem, you solved it ! Anyway i could simply use an object... I was blind